plotly.py Box Select extremely slow on first call on second and higher traces
Running plotly 5.23.0 from Jupyter lab 4.2.4 on Mac.
Drawing 3 traces of 111_000 points each, with "lines" only.
When drawing a Box Select rectangle over the first trace (trace 0), the kernel is busy for less than 1 second and then is available again. When drawing Box Select again over the first trace a few more times, it is always "fast" (less than 1 second).
But, when drawing a Box Select rectangle over a part of the second or third trace (trace 1, trace 2), the kernel is busy for 15 seconds. This extremely slow reaction is only present the first time that Box Select is drawn. From the second and consecutive times a Box Select rectangle is drawn over the same trace (second trace or third trace), it is also "fast".
This delay of 15 seconds on first usage of a Box Select is a major slow down for our users.
This is "lines" mode only, (no "markers"), so no points are selected, to avoid consequence of actual call backs to on_select. The behaviour is slower when "lines+markers" is used as mode, but I wanted to exclude any impact of the code the is referenced here  (plotly.js src/traces/scattergl/select.js line 25). Even when 0 points are selected with the Box Select, the effect is there, the first time. Also when using lines only and even for hidden plots an effect was found.
Also, when I invert the order of the data in the 3 traces, it is still the first trace (trace 0), that is still fast (but then that is the "top" trace in the drawing), on the first Box Select drawing over it, while trace 1 and trace 2 are slow.
Also, when I click a point, this triggers the on_click callback, that is fast and it does not remove the problem reported here. The first time a Box Select is used on a trace other than trace 0, even after a few clicks on the different traces, that first time is still slow.
I installed a fresh project with poetry with this set of dependencies:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
jupyterlab = "^4.2.4"
pandas = "^2.2.2"
matplotlib = "^3.9.2"
ipympl = "^0.9.4"
plotly = "^5.23.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.4.4"
pytest-mock = "^3.14.0"

On the plotly release page, version v5.23.0 is now (20 Aug 2024), marked as the latest https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.23.0.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import Layout
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Vivid
color = colors[1]

LEN = 111_000
WIDTH = 2000
FACTOR = 1.2
N_PLOTS = 3

fig = go.FigureWidget()
x = np.array(range(LEN))
y_data={}
for trace_idx in range(N_PLOTS):
    y_data[trace_idx] = np.array([e % WIDTH for e in x]) + (WIDTH * FACTOR * trace_idx)
    # alternative order can be obtained with
    # y_data[(N_PLOTS - 1) - trace_idx] = np.array([e % WIDTH for e in x]) + (WIDTH * FACTOR * trace_idx)

# In[ ]:

fig.data = []
for trace_idx in range(N_PLOTS):
    fig.add_scattergl(
        x=x,
        y=y_data[trace_idx],
        mode="lines+markers" if trace_idx<0 else "lines",
        marker=dict(color=colors[trace_idx], size=4),
        line=dict(color=color, width=1),
        xaxis="x",
        yaxis="y1",
        name=f"trace {trace_idx}",
        hovertemplate="",
        visible=True,
    )

def update_on_select(trace, points, selector):
    print(points.point_inds[0:3], datetime.now(), " on_select")
    fig.layout.title = str(points.point_inds[0:3]) + " " + str(len(points.point_inds)) + " select"

def update_on_click(trace, points, selector):
    print(points.point_inds[0:3], datetime.now(), "on_click")
    fig.layout.title = str(points.point_inds[0:3]) + " " + str(len(points.point_inds)) + " click"


fig.data[0].on_selection(update_on_select)
fig.data[0].on_click(update_on_click)

# In[ ]:

fig.update_layout(
    dragmode="select",
    yaxis_range=[-200, 100 + WIDTH * N_PLOTS * FACTOR],
)
display(fig)

Then I:

clicked a few time on a point => FAST on_select call back
drew a rectangular Box Select area on "trace 2" => SLOW (datetimenow is 15:51:55.77, but printing to log is 15:52:11, that is 15 seconds later)
drew AGAIN, a rectangular Box Select area on "trace 2" => FAST (datetimenow is 15:53:05.19, and printed to log at 15:53:05)

The printed logs from the log at the bottom of Jupyter Lab screen where:
15:51:30 [] 2024-08-20 15:51:28.363443 on_click  # click on top trace 2
15:51:35 [9062] 2024-08-20 15:51:35.256576 on_click  # click on bottom trace 0
15:51:40 [] 2024-08-20 15:51:40.554232 on_click  # click on top trace 2
15:51:42 [9173] 2024-08-20 15:51:42.023582 on_click  # click on bottom trace 0
15:52:11 [] 2024-08-20 15:51:55.771423  on_select  # drawing rectangular Box Select on top trace 2
15:53:05 [] 2024-08-20 15:53:05.192348  on_select  # drawing again rectangular Box Select on top trace 2

For comparison (not shown here), all rectangular Box Select drawing on trace 0 are fast, also from the first one.
Also, on_click, zoom, etc. on this graph all occur within 1 second. Only that first Box Select on a trace other than trace 0 is very slow. Also in our production notebook, with many more traces, everything is fast, except the first time a Box Select is used.
